# reading properties file into maven pom.xml not working

Tags: maven, pom.xml, properties-file

I need to use values from properties file in maven pom.xml, so i used properties-maven-plugin to read my properties file as follows

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/qura.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

qura.properties file contains something like this..

```
config.file.path = resources/python/config/test.py
```

I need use this config.file.path variable in resource element of pom.xml

pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/multilang/</directory>
        <includes>              
            <include>${config.file.path}</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
<resources>
```

But the value for ${config.file.path} is not taking up from qura.properties file and I couldn't find test.py file in jar.

what I'm doing wrong in this code?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

try using version 1.0.0 and removing spaces around equal sign in properties file.

eg:

```
key=value
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it does not matter whether you put the spaces or not around equal sign in properties file. You may need to check if the `${config.file.path}` exists in the directory specified by `${basedir}/multilang`

The below snippet works for me.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>${config.file.path}</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                    <inherited></inherited>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${basedir}/src/main/resources/qura.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks .. but adding maven-resources-plugin to include resources and removing spaces in properties files doesn't works for me. I'm sure that ${config.file.path} directory exists.

Comment: My general requirement is that i need to include resources specific to something like client-specific., say I want to include test1.py for client-1 and test2.py for client-2 like this.. so I tried to have this file names in properties file and tried using it inside pom.xml.. but it doesn't works for me.. Is there any other way to include resources like what I required